# How to set the title of jsp page using JSF 1.1 tags

Tags: java, jsf

I want to set the title of my JSP page

```
<head>
<title> ABCD
</title>
</head>
```

where ABCD is accessed from the backing bean is their a way to set the 
title using a JSF/Tomahawk tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using JSF 1.1 managed beans with JSPs, you will likely need to place a deferred evaluation expression (like `#{foo.bar}`) within an attribute that supports them. That is, use a `<h:outputText value="#{foo.bar}" />` tag.

JSF controls must be within the view (typically defined by the `<f:view>` tag.) Most JSP editors put the view within the `<body>` element, but it can be placed surrounding the `<html>` element if necessary.

Comment: yup u are right , but <h:outputtext> gives us a label HTML tag while i need a Title Tag as output. so ur answer still doesnt solves my problem

Comment: `outputText` shouldn't emit any tag so long as you don't set any HTML attributes on it. Use `<title><h:outputText value="#{foo.bar}" /></title>`